# Laravel - Trying to get property of non-object (trouble with auth::)

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm having difficulty with using 'Auth::' in laravel, I'm trying to get it working so it checks a users id, then displays all appointments that are using that users id. In the appointments table it uses 'user_id'

ErrorException in AppointmentController.php line 22:
Trying to get property of non-object

Appointments Controller (this is the line of the error)

```
  function index()
    {   
        $appointments = Appointment::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        return view ('appointment/userappointments',['appointments' => $appointments]);
    }
```

userappointments.blade

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Appointments')

@section('content')
    <h1>Your Appointments</h1>
     @foreach ($appointments as $appointment)
        <p>
                 <a href="{{url('details/'.$appointment->id)}}" >{{$appointment->doctor->name}} : {{$appointment->time}} : {{$appointment->date}}</a>   
        </p>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`$appointments = Appointment::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);`

to

`$appointments = Appointment::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();`

See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses) examples on Laravel docs.